# UISearchBar scope bar iOS 5.0 bug?

Tags: ios, uisearchbar

I think i found a bug in iOS 5.0 regarding UISearchBar and it's scope bar. I'm initially displaying the scope bar enabled in the XIB.

During runtime the scope bar is shown properly. However when clicked into the search textfield and clicking the cancel button, the scope bar is removed from screen. The screen area is still visible. See screenshots.

[image: UISearchBar still shows scope bar view area]
If someone has an idea on how to work around this problem, please let me know.

Thanks. Kay.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Setting searchBar.showsScopeBar has no visual effect. The showsScopeBar getter returns YES and yet no scope bars appear.

Answer (score 4):

Try implementing the 'searchBarShouldEndEditing' delegate to re-enable the scope bar when the search bar exists.

```
- (BOOL)searchBarShouldEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    self.searchBar.showsScopeBar = YES;
    [self.searchBar sizeToFit];
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchBar;
    return YES;
}
```

You can read more about this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9694432/916493)

Answer (score 0):

Please clarify what you expect/want to happen. There are several delegate methods. Here are a couple things I do in my SearchBarViewController:

First I make the VC be the delegate:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    searchBar.delegate = self;
}
```

Close and return to presenting view controller (my search box is modal):

```
- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    [[self presentingViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Filtering:

```
- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString {
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString scope:
     [[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles] objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];

    // Return YES to cause the search result table view to be reloaded.
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchScope:(NSInteger)searchOption {
    [self filterContentForSearchText:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar text] scope:
     [[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles] objectAtIndex:searchOption]];

    // Return YES to cause the search result table view to be reloaded.
    return YES;
}
```

Good luck,

Damien

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I would like to force the scope bar to stay visible all the time. I even implemented a subclass of UISearchBar...

Comment: Did you override searchBarCancelClicked: in the delegate to ensure it isn't doing anything? Also, are you using a UISearchDisplayController? I understand you subclassed the UISearchBar, but what about the controller? I remember I had issues using the UISearchBar without the UISearchDisplayController provided in IB. I just tested my own code, and when I click cancel the tableview clears. Is that what you want to happen?

Comment: Yes i use UISearchDisplayController and yes i also did implement searchBarCancelClicked: No results! :-(

Comment: So to clarify, is your only problem that the Eintrag rows don't disappear?

Comment: No. The problem is that the scope bar of the UISearchBar disappears. It should look like this: [link](http://www.osxentwicklerforum.de/index.php?page=Attachment&attachmentID=3582&h=73d3447bb1e6588ccaf4b7ea3b31bc34d47fde20)

Comment: Hmm, that link doesn't work for me. However, I don't use the scope bar so I probably can't be of much help. Good luck debugging.