# I want to show navigation bar when i clicked on search bar

Tags: iphone, ios

I create search bar with scope bar. when I click on search bar that time navigation bar will be hide. Search bar can override on navigation bar. I want to show search bar below navigation bar. How can I do?

Comment: go through this answer it might give you a hint http://stackoverflow.com/a/9694432/2695503

Answer (score 0):

just convert this code into hrs it will work

```
-(void)searchDisplayControllerDidEndSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller{
    NSLog(@"search cancelled");
    _searchBar.frame=CGRectMake(0, 60, 320, 40);
    _arrButtons=nil;
 [_tableFriendList reloadData];


}
-(void)searchDisplayControllerDidBeginSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller{
    NSLog(@"hey.......");



    _searchBar.frame=CGRectMake(0, 60, 320, 40);
    //_tableFriendList.frame=CGRectMake(0, 140, 320,400);

    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden: NO animated: YES];

    controller.active = YES;

    [self.view addSubview:controller.searchBar];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:controller.searchBar];



}
```